# How to run n Task and keep the order of them

Tags: c#

I have method that listen to communication channel.

Each package that i have i put in concurrent queue and call Task.Run to handle this input.

The handle method create new Task that do ConcurrentQueue TryDequeue and do something on the package ( take the first queue input ).

How can i keep the order of the Task ? 
How can i be sure that Task1 that handle package1 will be handled and will be finish his task before Task2  that handle package2 and finish his task ?

There can be a scenario that Task1 will take package1 and Task2 will take package2 but Task2 will be finish its running before Task1 ... and this i must avoid.

How to do it ?

Comment: sounds like  `for` or `foreach` would work well.

Comment: no ...  sorry ... it will not work .. the for/each will run task and not control on the order that they will finished

Comment: If you want to guarantee processing order then you can't parallelize the processing.

Comment: i must have new task on each queue input.
i have communication listener open that collect packages all the time.

Comment: Why do you need tasks and stuff when you need to run the operations sequentially? Just use single thread and a foreach (or whatever to loop). btw what do you mean by package?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use an [ActionBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) . It queues incoming messages and processes them using one or more Tasks. By default, only one Task is used but you can change that. If you use only one Task, the message processing order is guaranteed

Comment: So... you are saying: The tasks can run parallel, but they must finish in order. So... I understand that you want the results of each task is written in order to some queue or file or whatever... am I correct?

Comment: The question is too vague to answer properly. What is it about "finishing" that you need to prevent the second task from doing before the first? How is this definition of "finishing" compatible with the idea of running the tasks concurrently? Are there a finite number of concurrent tasks, in which case they could just write their result to a specific index in an array? Alternatively, how about putting the running tasks themselves into a queue, where you dequeue an item and then wait on it before moving on to the next? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: finishing Task is when the Task can send event to the upper level. The event contain int of the Task result. Because i don't know how many Task i will have i can't have Task on queue because i can have too much Task and this can break my performance.